# ffmpeg - error message "Invalid data found when processing input" when trying to convert a video file but video is playable

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg version

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.1_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin -fno-stack-check' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
```

When I try to process [this video](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/filestore.getselect.co/IMG_0029.mp4) using this command

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_0029.mp4 -y newvideo2.mp4
```

I get this output

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f8a1f008200] could not find corresponding trex (id 1)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f8a1f008200] could not find corresponding track id 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f8a1f008200] trun track id unknown, no tfhd was found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f8a1f008200] error reading header
IMG_0029.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I don't understand what is the problem as the video is playable.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to FFmpeg 4.3 or newer, or use a build from the current git master branch.

Relevant commit: [mov: Support fake moov boxes disguised as hoov](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=a13841b79782eb09222d953e9c7d3cd00fefecf3).

Comment: Why? Do you think it is a bug with this version of ffmpeg?

Comment: @Rotem I did not look at the git log or perform a git bisect, but it appears there is a bug that was fixed. I could reproduce the problem in 4.2.1, but not in 4.3.1 and git master.

Comment: thanks @llogan. I did manage to pass the issue with version 4.3.1, however when I run a simple command `ffmpeg -i IMG_0029.mp4 -y newvideo2.mp4` it only produces 5 seconds video instead of 2 minutes video. Do you know why?

Comment: @Rotem I don't know why. I assumed it was 5 seconds the whole time and thought the commit I mentioned fixed the issue. What created the file? What shows that it is 2 minutes? Consider submitting a [bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/). Make sure to show your command, the complete log, use ffmpeg from git master (you can use homebrew w/ `--HEAD` option or download at zeranoe or evermeet), and provide a link to the file.

Comment: I know it is 2 minutes video because I can view 2 minutes and 20 seconds long video (remember, the original video is playable everywhere). I already submitted a bug https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8876 but no new info for now.

Comment: Tried to use the latest build and still it only produces 5 seconds video

Comment: @Rotem Testing a version from git master is a requirement for bug reports or else the report will be closed or you will be asked to provide the output from the build from git master (if someone else does not do it for you).

Comment: I did use the latest snapshot build from https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/ is not the same as latest git master?

Comment: I have created another ticket - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8883#ticket

Comment: @Rotem I don't know how often evermeet makes a build derived from git master. Looks like the version on the site is less than 24 hrs old, so good enough. As long as it's not older than two weeks or so should be fine. The two tickets are duplicates. The `Invalid data found when processing input` error was already "fixed" by a later commit missing in your old ffmpeg that you used for the report, so the report has changed to address the missing 15 seconds.